# Multiple prepared statements into many to many relationship table using last id

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

### [Updated code from suggestions]

Currently I have two tables in my database.  The second table is a junction table for multiple categories from each unique id from the first table.  Nothing too special.

**Need to accomplish:**

I'd like to use two prepared statements where specifically the second statement gets the ID from the first and loops through.  Here's what I've tried:

```
//set autocommit to off
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);

//first table
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO birds (db_category, db_class) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt1->bind_param('ss',$_POST['db_category'],$_POST['db_class']);
$stmt1->execute();
//get the inserted ID
$lastID = $stmt1->insert_id;
$stmt1->close();

//second table (many to many)
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO birdsBiome (birds_id, biomes_id) VALUES (?, ?)");

$arrayValue = $_POST['biomeCheck'];

foreach ($arrayValue as $arrayInsert) {
$stmt2->bind_param('ii', $lastID, $arrayInsert);
$stmt2->execute();
}
$stmt2->close();

//commit both statements                    
$conn->commit();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: [$lastID = $stmt1->insert_id;](http://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) ? also youre not executing the first query.

Comment: that easy?  Am I also closing and executing the prepared statement correctly?

Comment: You are not executing or closing the first statement separately only the connection at the end.

Comment: I would assign `$lastID = $stmt1->insert_id;` right after the execute of the first query but I guess both ways will work and have the bind_param inside the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the last insert id as a property of the mysqli object:

```
$lastID = $conn->insert_id;
```

Or alternatively you don't have to store $lastID at all if you access it within your SQL:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO birdsBiome (birds_id, biomes_id) 
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?)");
```

By the way, in your code example above you didn't execute $stmt1, so there will be no last insert id anyway.

Comment: But given he will execute the later on a `foreach` and that `birds_id` is `auto increment` it will replace the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` so I don't think it will fit this case.

Comment: @Prix, it depends if the birdsBiome has an auto-increment column. If it doesn't, then the last insert id will not change.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Correct, no auto-increment.  I believe it didn't work because exactly what you pointed out that I didn't execute $stmt1